# check if a column is composed of ones

Tags: matlab

does it exist a function built-in in matlab that checks if a column is all composed of ones? If it doesn't exist, there are some ways to build a function that work to achieve that porpouse?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`all(A==1)` should return `true` if it's composed of only `1`s. Note that if you have any floating point precision errors, you should use `all( abs(A-1) < eps )`.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare all entries of a column to 1 and sum the result

```
if sum(A(:,1)~=1)==0
    % all ones
else
    % not all ones
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If A is a column vector:

```
A=[1 1 1 1]';
```

You could check like this:

```
sum(A==1)==length(A)
ans =

 1
```